Is it gambling?
Assalamu Aleykum Wa Rahmatullahi Wa Barakatuhu
is it Haram to open cases(loot boxes) in games without buying them(spending any money real or in game)
in game you get free case(loot box) if you play well enough, so i wanted to know, if we are allowed to open this cases or it's still considered Haram (gambling or the random factor or anything else)
or in other game you play good you get random reward, to open it you must click a few times, then you will get something random, again is it gambling? im not buying anything, just free gifts, but im worried about the 'chance' of winning something

I don't know about the Islamic view and hope that there will soon an answer based on the Quran or other Islamic teachings. From the teaching based on Christianity, there is no randomness as THE ALMIGHTY (by different names in different religions) rules ALL. The root of the sin of gambling (citation needed) is in challenging THE ALMIGHTY.
